# Single point line (two verteces on top of each other) = NO POINT DRAWN?

Tags: opengl

Code is currently:

```
with TOpenGLAPIVersion110 do
begin
// render ray
glLineWidth( 1 );
glBegin(GL_LINES);

// begin of ray is dark gray
glColor3f( 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 );
glVertex2f( mRay.Start.X, mRay.Start.Y);

glColor3f( 0.75, 0.75, 0.75 );
glVertex2f( mRay.Stop.X, mRay.Stop.Y);

glEnd();
end;
```

When x,y,z coordinates of Ray.Start is equal to those of Ray.Stop OpenGL does not draw a "point".

Why is this ?

Are the end points of lines "not inclusive" ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL broadly does what you say. A point is a point, and a line is a line. A line of length zero does not become a point; you asked to draw a line with no length, so OpenGL draws exactly that: nothing.

The same goes for a triangle with no area (two or more of the vertices have the same position). You don't get a line; you get nothing.

This is important because rasterization happens in window coordinates, after any viewing transformations happen. So when I say "triangle with no area", what I *really* mean is "triangle with no area *from your perspective*". If you happen to be looking at a triangle edge on, it won't have area from your perspective. So the rasterizer will not draw a line; it will draw nothing. Because a triangle is infinitely thin, so there's nothing to draw.

The same goes for lines; if you look at a line directly down the axis of the line, you see nothing. You don't want such a line to become a point.

So if you mean to draw a point, you need to tell OpenGL to do that.